# Does the unsubscribe method in Rx unsubscribe the last subscriber only or it stops event posting for the whole stream?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I am interesting in how Rx handles the Subscription#unsubscribe method. For instance, we have

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.from(veryBigList)
                .map(value -> convertValue(value))
                .map(value1 -> saveToDb(value))
                // .... maybe more operators
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();
        // ...
        subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Does it provide a guarantee that unsubscribing the subscription stops emitting events in the whole stream?

Comment: Unsubscribe has an eventual guarantee (also called best-effort) that everything in the whole chain gets unsubscribed. Did you find a case where this doesn't happen?

Comment: @akarnokd No, I didn't. I just found an internal API which seems to rely on that unsubscribing should stop emitting events to the subscriber only keeping the rest of the stream alive

Answer (score 0):

It depends; if you have a `cache()` or `share()` then unsubscription propagation will stop there.